# Multiple video overlay - need advice

Tags: video, overlay

I'm working on a project and I need some advice.
Just some background, Im not a programmer though 
at times I do some fiddling and I am generally
comfortable with more specific terms.

Now for the actual issue, I have a folder with 10 small videos (4/7 secs max each) and I would like to display them full screen looping and overlaid.

I'm not too sure on at what should I be looking at, I thought maybe processing but my most serious issue if that I cant even ask for help since I don't know what I need.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by 'overlaid'?

Comment: Hi, I mean if I have 4 videos each one plays with with 25% opacity on top of each other.

Comment: A person recommended me doing it either in Max Sp or OpenFrameworks?

Answer (score 0):

What I've been told by the guy writing the book on AVFoundation is that you should use AVFoundation. I also found a sample of code here in SOF that has an example of it working with a clock. Check out the link.

[iOS AVFoundation - Show a time display over a video and export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749450/ios-avfoundation-show-a-time-display-over-a-video-and-export)

Also, when trying to explain what your looking for, check out WeatherHD. I'm not affiliated, it's just a great app.

I'll be doing something very similar for a client in the next couple of weeks and it's all new to me as well, so, I'll post what I learn.

Doug
www.smittenapp.com
www.martialapps.com