# Video filter using Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video-processing

I would like to apply filters(Lomo, Instant, Diana, Loko and Old Time etc) on videos taking from  my iPhone application, like PATH iPhone application doing. 
How can i do that? Is there any sample application available online? 
Please advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply "filters" to AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156872/how-to-apply-filters-to-avcapturevideopreviewlayer)

Comment: See also [Capturing video while processing it through a shader on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228406/capturing-video-while-processing-it-through-a-shader-on-iphone) which handles the case of recording this video (see the comments on that question for more about this).