# Capture video from cam + custom view into single video file

Tags: ios, video, overlay

I wonder if it's possible in iOS 4 or 5 to save into a single video file not just a stream from camera, but a stream from camera WITH custom view(s) overlaid. Custom view will contain few labels with transparent background. Those labels will show additional info: current time and GPS coordinates. And every video player must be able to playback that additional info.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to process each frame and use AVAssetWriter to record the processed frame.You can refer to this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4944594/379941 .

And you can process CVImageBufferRef then    use **AVAssetWriterPixelBufferAdaptor's appendPixelBuffer:withPresentationTime:** method to export.

And I  strongly suggest using OpenCV to process frame. this is a nice tutorial http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/. OpenCV library is very great.

Comment: @stuser974349 it depend what process to do with frame.If tracking Face, it has 4 fps.But if tracking specific color, it has about 20fps.