# How do i save a video (mp4 format) using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapture

I have set up the input, and the output for the AVCapture session and also the delegate

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

is getting called. How do I convert the frames to a mp4 video file and save it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an AVAssetWriter to compress the data and write to MP4. These two samples contain code that does this:

http://www.gdcl.co.uk/2013/02/20/iPhone-Pause.html

http://www.gdcl.co.uk/2013/02/20/iOS-Video-Encoding.html

G

Comment: thanks @Geraint Davies. This link [Video Recorder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944083/can-use-avcapturevideodataoutput-and-avcapturemoviefileoutput-at-the-same-time) also helped me

Comment: Hi Geraint, I used iOS Video Encoding to live video broadcast video to rtsp server using the code of "Encoder demo" of "GTCL" site. please help me. When I am using your code, only video gets uploaded using RTSP server not audio. When I am adding audio to this code, then get crash in "onNALU" method.

Comment: @NameisNilay i have same issue , did u manage to overcome with this ??