# Can I use AVCaptureSession to read a video from a file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession

I was writing an app that does some real-time video processing using an `AVCaptureSession` with a `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` as output and an `AVCaptureDeviceInput` with the camera as input. Then the requirements changed, and now I need to save the video file as it comes in, and process the video (it no longer needs to be in real-time)

Is it possible to either a) attach an `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` and a `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to the same `AVCaptureSession`? Trying it and preliminary searches both suggest this isn't possible, but someone here might know a way.

b) Record to a file using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` and then use the file as in input to the `AVCaptureSession` instead of the camera? This would allow me to reuse all the code from before. I haven't been able to find a way to use a file as an input to an `AVCaptureSession` though.

If neither of these methods are possible, what is the best method to save and process a video on iOS (either simultaneously or sequentially)?

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is nearly three years old, however it helped me in the right direction, and I figured I'd post an answer about what I did.

In order to "capture" video from a file, I used the usual AVPlayer setup, eg:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html

Then used the AVPlayerItem addOutput method to add an AVPlayerItemVideoOutput instance, like in the GreenScreen demo:

https://github.com/alokc83/iOS-Example-Collections/blob/master/WWDC_2012_SourceCode/iOS/517%20-%20Real-Time%20Media%20Effects%20and%20Processing%20during%20Playback/AVGreenScreenPlayer/AVGreenScreenPlayer/GSPlayerView.m

But without the filtering, and instead of using CVDisplayLink, I just used a timer with an interval of 33ms, and used hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime and copyPixelBufferForItemTime on the AVPlayerItems currentTime value. This was sufficient to "capture" at around 25fps, which was sufficient for the purpose.

I achieved this using Delphi, however the above should provide enough clues to be able to do the same in ObjectiveC, Swift, C#, or whatever your choice of language that is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another post that suggests a possible scenario:

[How do i save a video (mp4 format) using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478128/how-do-i-save-a-video-mp4-format-using-avcapturevideodataoutput)

Basically, use the AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate method:

captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:

to process the frame as you'd like. You can then use AVAssetWriter to actually store the data.

Regarding your point a), you are correct, you cannot use AVCaptureMovieFileOutput and AVCaptureVideoDataOutput simultaneously.