# Add Date and time on recorded video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video-recording

In my application there feature of recording video, I want to add time and date details on the recorded video.

Simply i can add while it running within the app but what i want to do is If i export that video in Photo app or email that video, than also date and time should be there.

I checked this sample code from apple but in this text can be static that will remain same all time.

[AVSimpleEditor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVSimpleEditoriOS/Introduction/Intro.html)

Can any one guide me or any link ? How to add time stamp detail on video..

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you got anything???

Comment: @murugha23 No, not get any solution yet.

Comment: how about the possiblity of adding dynamic content to CALayer?

Comment: @murugha23 well not sure, i had try at that time with various way but not successfully. I had tried by adding in CATextlayer too but it was taling last/first value.

Comment: now i started to record a video with a overlay by screen recording

Comment: @user1111 with this way you able to record with timestamp.

Comment: yes! but we cannot add audio with screen captured video

Comment: @user1111 so isn't it useful? because of above drawback?

Comment: yes! and also  i altered [this code](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos) to add a text continuously. By this way you can add timestamp with that.

Comment: @iTroyd23 Hii.. you have added text(time-stamp) on recording/recorded video? if yes can you share your code please if possible?

Comment: hi, i just created a video of duration 1 min only... that embedded with time stamps.

Comment: okay, thank for reply.. can you share it with me I will check for more than 1 min if possible?

Comment: i'm out of station, i will give it on monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GPUImage Class](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) by Brad Larson , It allows you to add filter to image and video as per your requirment . I just implement the exact thing that you asked for in one of my projects recently.

What i did was use UILabel as `GPUImageUIElement` and added it to `GPUImageNormalBlendFilter`. I updated the label text with every callback and it worked like a charm.

Here is the code:

```
filterView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.videoRecordView.frame];
videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];

movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(1920,1080)];

[self.view addSubview:filterView];
movieWriter.encodingLiveVideo = YES;
movieWriter.encodingLiveVideo = YES;
videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;


GPUImageNormalBlendFilter *blendFilter1 = [[GPUImageNormalBlendFilter alloc] init];


UILabel *timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 635, 768.0f, 50.0f)];

timeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:fontSize];
timeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
timeLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

uiElementInput = [[GPUImageUIElement alloc] initWithView:timeLabel];
[uiElementInput addTarget:blendFilter1];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy  hh : mm : ss a"];


[blendFilter1 addTarget:filterView];
[blendFilter1 addTarget:movieWriter];
[videoCamera addTarget:blendFilter1];


__unsafe_unretained GPUImageUIElement *weakUIElementInput = uiElementInput;
    [filter setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock:^(GPUImageOutput * filter, CMTime frameTime){
       
    timeLabel.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
    
    float sizefont =[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:KfontSize] floatValue];
    timeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:(sizefont)? sizefont:30];
    NSDate * originalDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:interval];

    NSString *timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:originalDate];
    timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", timeString];
    [weakUIElementInput update];
}];
```

I Know question is old but might help someone as it took me a while to find this.

Answer (score 1):

The sample you linked shows you how to get 90% of the way. The last step is to look at the docs for [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This class allows you to add any core animation to a video. How you do this is by adding the animation to [CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).

If you use a CATextLayer you can animate the string property.